# Pipelining stalls and data-forwarding

Tags: assembly, pipeline, riscv, riscv32, rars-simulator

Assuming no data forwarding, and no hazard detection I've been trying to see if I can optimize this code but since 4 of the 5 statements are data-dependent in some way I keep getting 5 stalls or "NOP" operations. Am I missing something or is there something I can do to decrease the stalls within?
code below

1. add x15, x12, x11
2. ld x13, 8(x15)
3. ld x12, 0(x2)
4. or x13, x15, x13
5. sd x13, 0(x15)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Da9.png)

Optimize the lines by reducing the amount of stalls within the pipeline without using data forwarding or more statements

Comment: I don't see how to improve this. We can move (3.) around but still just covers one `nop` of the six needed

Comment: A short chain of mostly-dependent instructions doesn't leave much room for doing anything.  Interleave it with surrounding code.  Or if this is a loop body, try to software-pipeline it.  Note that real-world CPUs *will* have bypass forwarding; examples like this serve to illustrate why it's worth the transistor cost, since it's hard to hide latency when even simple integer instructions have multiple cycles of latency before the results are ready.

Comment: Let's note that when bypass/forward ***is*** employed by the hardware, this is probably already the best sequence, since with a traditional 5-stage pipeline, the (usage of the result from) `ld` is going to have a stall even with a bypass.